# Is the type cast necessary when using malloc in C?

Tags: c, types, casting, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

I just learned how to use the malloc function, and my teacher mentioned that it's necessary to make a type cast when passing the memory address to the pointer. For example, here's a code to get 16 new bytes allocated (4 ints) using malloc:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   int *p;
   p = (int *)malloc(4*sizeof(int));

   return 0;
}
```

My question: is the (int *) cast on the right side of the attribution necessary? After all p is already a pointer to ints, so the pointer arithmetic should work fine even without that cast.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need the cast if you are using malloc in C++ code.

For C it's preferable to *not* use the cast as it is (a) unnecessary and (b) can mask problems that would otherwise be reported by the compiler.

Comment: And then, it's C++, it's better to use `new` unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Furthermore, the code can be made a bit more robust by writing `p = malloc(4 * sizeof *p);`.